# Annotator for Relationship Extraction

Tags: regex, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, gate

I have a set of urls in a text file. For each url in that text file, I want to tag the entities and relationships in the text contained in that url.

I am aware of the entity taggers like Stanford NER, NLTK and GATE which can perform the entity tagging. However, I am more interested in relationship extraction.

In order to extract relationships, I am thinking of annotating the text contained in those urls for training purpose. For this, I do not want to do manual annotation. I can write few regex to extract the relationship which I want, however it would be difficult to scale up.

Is there a tool where in I can specify what I want to annotate?

For example:

> " Rob is working as the Director of ABC organization. He graduated from
>   XYZ University "

Here, I want to extract the *affiliations* relationship, so intuitively I would like to annotate words which describe the affiliations like *working*, *graduated*.

Edit:
By "a set of URLs in the text file", I mean I have about 200 links to certain webpages in that text file, each of the webpage contains some text. I want to analyse (annotate) that text.

Comment: What do you mean by "a set of urls in a text file" ? Can you please give use an example ? Can please specify your answer...

Comment: Edited the definition of "a set of urls". Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PR in GATE that that will pair arguments and create instances
for you. You must therefore create instances that are relevant to your problem.

You can:

- write a custom PR
- or write some JAPE with Java RHS

You can probably split your corpus on a training and a test dataset.

You can use the GATE training course about Relation Extration that contains all you need:

- Slides: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun14/module-3-ml/module-11-relations.pdf
- Materials: http://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun14/module-3-ml/module-11-relation-exercise.zip

Comment: I am trying to write bootstrapping-based method for relation extraction. I have come across Snowball, DIPRE and KnowItAll. I am following there work and I think it would be relevant in this case.